# GIS Need a Mapping sdk for turn by turn navigation API on Win CE c#

Tags: c#, mapping, gis

I need to develop an on vehicle mapping program for a Windows CE device
Think like youre regular satnav program with pre defined routes and a few extras

I need a c# gis mapping SDK that I can use

It must:

- have Cheap licensing model, (Google maps might work but a commercial license is too expensive as it's per device)
- Support for Vector and Raster maps
- Turn by turn routing & route calculation

Can anyone recommend a mapping API to me or give me a list of vendors?
Thanks
Ro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be of use to anyone else searching
I found the best places to search were for companies who provide iphone apps for navigation

www.sygic.com have a pretty good naviagation app and also sell an iphone app